# How to change svg color on Hover

Tags: css, svg

every one , i am using angular and i have a svg , html like :

```
  <button
    type="button"
    class="filter-icon-wrapper padding-0 border-0 outline-0 bg-transparent pointer"
  >
    <mat-icon class="filter-icon" *ngIf="!isDateType" svgIcon="filter_default">filter_alt</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

this is the svg source code filter_default:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 11.9 11.91"><defs><style>.cls-2{fill:#707070;}</style></defs><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><g id="Path_7587" data-name="Path 7587"><path class="cls-2" d="M6.8,11.91a1,1,0,0,1-.58-.19l-1.7-1.19a1,1,0,0,1-.43-.83V5.52L.3,1.73A1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,.29.3,1,1,0,0,1,1,0h9.88a1,1,0,0,1,.72.29,1,1,0,0,1,0,1.44L7.82,5.52v5.37a1,1,0,0,1-.19.59A1,1,0,0,1,6.8,11.91ZM1,1,5.09,5.11V9.7L6.8,10.9l0-5.79L10.9,1V1Z"/></g></g></g></svg>
```

I want to know how can i change the svg color when mouse hover , thanks all of your help！

Comment: Add CSS: `svg:hover { stroke: red; }`

Comment: if i have many case like this <mat-icon/> and refer to a svg , will it affect other svg style ? thanks for your reply

Answer (score 6):

```css
#Path_7587 .cls-2 {
  fill:#707070;
}
#Path_7587 .cls-2:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 11.9 11.91"><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><g id="Path_7587" data-name="Path 7587"><path class="cls-2" d="M6.8,11.91a1,1,0,0,1-.58-.19l-1.7-1.19a1,1,0,0,1-.43-.83V5.52L.3,1.73A1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,.29.3,1,1,0,0,1,1,0h9.88a1,1,0,0,1,.72.29,1,1,0,0,1,0,1.44L7.82,5.52v5.37a1,1,0,0,1-.19.59A1,1,0,0,1,6.8,11.91ZM1,1,5.09,5.11V9.7L6.8,10.9l0-5.79L10.9,1V1Z"/></g></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have try this solustion , but seems .cls-2 {
  fill:#707070;
} will be override by other style and cannot  show the color correct

Comment: Elements id have the priority in CSS since they are the most specific. You just have to use the id. I made an edit, I hope it will help

Comment: thanks for your help ! , i found a way to make it work now

Comment: Can I ask how ?

Comment: i add the answer in this question too

    1. rename the class name in svg from cls-2 to floatTextIcon

    2. in the scss file add such code

    :host ::ng-deep .floatTextIcon:hover { fill: #3a464d; }

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the first answer, with one correction. The right class to modify is **cls-2**:

```
.cls-2:hover {
  fill:red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ， but it doesn't work , is there any way forced to change the hover color ?

Comment: You mean you want to change the icon color when hovering on the whole button?

Answer (score 0):

thanks all of your help , i try ng-deep and now work fine

1. rename the class name in svg from cls-2 to floatTextIcon
2. in the scss file add such code

   :host ::ng-deep .floatTextIcon:hover {
   fill: #3a464d;
   }

Answer (score 0):

Changing the icon color when hovering a button:

```
button .cls-2 {
  fill: #888;
}

button:hover .cls-2 {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

button .cls-2 {
  fill: #888;
}

button:hover .cls-2 {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<button>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 11.9 11.91"><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" width="32" height="32"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><g id="Path_7587" data-name="Path 7587"><path class="cls-2" d="M6.8,11.91a1,1,0,0,1-.58-.19l-1.7-1.19a1,1,0,0,1-.43-.83V5.52L.3,1.73A1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,.29.3,1,1,0,0,1,1,0h9.88a1,1,0,0,1,.72.29,1,1,0,0,1,0,1.44L7.82,5.52v5.37a1,1,0,0,1-.19.59A1,1,0,0,1,6.8,11.91ZM1,1,5.09,5.11V9.7L6.8,10.9l0-5.79L10.9,1V1Z"/></g></g></g></svg>
</button>
```